# How do I efficiently override Laravel's generated auth routes?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have two applications, the routes file of the working one is below:

routes.php

```
<?php

Route::auth();

Route::group(["prefix" => "api"], function() {
    Route::resource("places", "PlacesController");
    Route::resource("users", "UsersController");
    Route::group(["prefix" => "auth"], function() {
        Route::get("/", "AuthController@GetAuth");
        Route::get("logout", 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
    });
});

Route::get('/', 'RedirectController@toAngular');
```

I have the same thing in another application but it is not working. I get an `InvalidArgumentException` because it can't find the login.blade.php file which I deleted because it is handled by Angular. How do I properly and most efficiently override the /login and /register GET routes generated by `Route::auth()`?

Comment: Can't you just remove Route::auth();? Or just define your own before it, first route that matches is used.

Comment: correct, just dont use Route::auth() and define them yourself, as that is all Route::auth() is doing, just literally registering some simple routes.

Comment: That is how I had it before. I just didn't think that was the best way. But okay, thanks!

Comment: Remove Route::auth(); and define your own routes.

Comment: I like this kind of answers... "Q: How do I do this" "A: Don't do this, do that". Thanks to @Sovon for pointing out how to actually override a route originally defined by `Route::auth()` : define it again, **after** the auth routes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to override  /login and /register, you can just add those two routes after declaring `Route::auth()` like following:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'auth.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
Route::get('register', ['as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm']);
```

As the application can't find the 'login.blade.php' which is actually returned from controller method, not in routes, then you need to override the showLoginForm method in AuthController and return what view you want to load.

```
public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('path.to.your.view');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is actually an answer to the question, not like those "Don't do this, do that". I was trying to override the register route, to disable it, but was defining it *before*, thinking that Laravel would not define a route that already exists. Since it actually does, the route has to be overriden *after* `Route::auth()`. Upvoted to thank you.